# Cannot disable authentication for Jenkins when running from command line

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins 2.14 installed and have 1 admin user with no password.  When running as a Windows service I can login fine.  When running war file from command prompt, authentication always fails even though I'm using the same credentials. Why is this so?  How can I disable authentication when running from command prompt?

I have tried setting security to false in config but still get asked to login when running from command prompt.

Comment: try to open CMD as admin, maybe it will help

Comment: sorry, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: When running war file from command prompt first open the command prompt as admin. I will post this as an answer so I can upload a picture.

Answer (score 0):

**When running war file from command prompt first open the command prompt as admin.**

[image]